# Azure Data Factory error in self hosted integration runtime

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have running my Azure Data Factory pipeline that is configured to run in a self hosted integration runtime. I have installed integrated runtime version 5.22.8297.1. My Data factory pipeline has two activities - Copy Activity and Azure function activity. When I execute the pipeline I am getting the following error -

"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.DataTransfer.ExternalActivities.Common, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Any idea what could be missing or am I using the right version of the integration runtime. The runtime is installed on Windows VM.

Comment: Do you get data while clicking preview data on source dataset?

Comment: Clicking preview data on source dataset is working fine. This error is generated when the Azure Function activity is executed.

Comment: Check if this [Microsoft document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/self-hosted-integration-runtime-troubleshoot-guide?tabs=data-factory#self-hosted-ir-could-not-load-file-or-assembly) solves the SHIR issue

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a known issue in 5.22.8297.1 SH-IR version that's fixed in 5.22.8312.1, per the ADF SH-IR release notes (https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=853077)